# JavaScript: Custom property with vars

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I have a JavaScript function like that:

```
function someCoolActionHere(input) {
    return { input: 'someValue' };
}
```

This function returns an JS object. The function parameter `input` is a string (e.g. `name`) and the value of the paramter variable should be used as property name in the object, not `input` itself. Example:

```
someCoolActionHere('hello');
// => { 'hello': 'someValue' }
```

How could that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
function someCoolActionHere(input) {
    obj = {};
    obj[input] = 'someValue';
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't do it with a literal. You'll have to use `[]` to set the property.

```
var obj = {};
obj[input] = "someValue";
return obj;
```